# Looping through cell values in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to write a program that will loop through all the cells in an excel sheet and if one starts with a '#' it should display a message. here's the code:

(template is a worksheet variable)

```
Private Function processTemplate()
    Dim total As Long
    total = template.UsedRange.count

    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    While count <= total
        If template.Cells(count).Value Like "[#]*" Then 'Here I get a error
            MsgBox "Found #"
            End If
        count = count + 1
    Wend
End Function
```

I have isolated the error to using a variable inside of cells(). If I replace count with some number (like 8) it works fine. I am getting error 1004 on the line `If template.Cells(count).Value Like "[#]*" Then`
If I make total an `Integer` it has the same error at the same place. After about 2-3 hrs of research/banging my head on the wall I have no idea. I initially got the error when assigning `template.cells(row, col).Value` to a string variable.

**Here's my code now:**

```
Private Sub processTemplate()
    MsgBox Len("")
    Dim str As String
    Dim rows As Long
    Dim cols As Long
    rows = template.UsedRange.Height
    cols = template.UsedRange.Width

    Dim row As Integer
    row = 1
    While row < rows
        Dim col As Integer
        col = 1
        While col < cols
            str = template.Cells(row, col).Text
            If Len(str) > 0 Then
                If Left(template.Cells(row, col).Text, 1) = "#" Then
                    MsgBox "Found IT"
                End If
            End If
            Rem MsgBox template.Parent.Name & ": " & template.Name & ", Cell(" & row & ", " & col & "): " & template.Cells(row, col).Value
            col = col + 1
        Wend
        row = row + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Now I get the error on `str = template.Cells(row, col).Text`

Comment: template.cells(count).value will starts at 0 which gives template.cells(0).value.  try start at 1: count = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a **sub** rather than a **function**

We loop over all the cells in **UsedRange** looking for a **#** as the first character in the cell.

```
Sub FindThePound()
    Dim r As Range, pound As String, template As Worksheet
    pound = "#"
    Set template = ActiveSheet
    For Each r In template.UsedRange
        If Left(r.Value, 1) = pound Then
            MsgBox "Found # in " & r.Address(0, 0)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

This version loops over all the cells, but does not test cells containing formulas

```
Sub FindThePound()
    Dim r As Range, pound As String, template As Worksheet
    pound = "#"
    Set template = ActiveSheet
    For Each r In template.UsedRange
        If r.HasFormula = False Then
            If Left(r.Value, 1) = pound Then
                MsgBox "Found # in " & r.Address(0, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: The code works, and is in a sense, a correct answer, but with absolutely zero explanation of what OP was doing wrong or what your code did right...

Comment: This mostly works, it throws an error when it runs into a formula though. (r.Value = error 2015 in the debugger) the address is cell B14 the contents are: (=+B13+B12), normally if there are values in B13 & B12, this evaluates fine.

Comment: I have another hopefolly small issue. I have two strings, one of them obtained by `split` the other in a cell, when I print them with `msgbox` they look the same however an `if...Then` statement says they are not. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could use find/ find next function which i guess bit faster than looping through each cell and do string comparison.

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500") 'Provide the search range
    Set c = .Find(2, lookin:=xlValues) ' searching for  2 in cell value
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = c.Address 'first occurance
        Do 
            'do whatever you want to do with the matches even replace them
            c.Value = 5 
            Set c = .FindNext(c) 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress 
    End If 
End With
```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Eventually I will need to copy all cells that do not have the '#' I will be interpreting those as instructions to get data from another sheet, with the part after # to be the location. So I will need to go through all the cells anyway.